# Nested inheritance with classes

Tags: class, inheritance

I have a question regarding how a child class inherits from another child class which inherits from the base class. Consider the following: Triangle inherits from Shape, and RightTriangle inherits from Triangle. I have an image below to describe the scenario.

**Can it be possible for RightTriangle to inherit directly from Shape (Given that it is also a shape)?**

[image: Imgur]

Comment: What do you mean by inherit directly ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal ; it is *possible* to inherit directly, sure, but you'd be lacking the triangle layer which would be confusing.
And this would also make you unable to use triangle-specific properties or methods, which is probably something you'd need in a right-triangle. Possible, yes, practical/advised, definitely no.
Also, this is probably not a question for SO, but more likely for programmers.stackechange.com

Comment: There does not seem to be anything in this question that justifies a C# tag. Any answer that applies to C# would apply to another language with a similar inheritance model.

Comment: `RightTriangle` already is a `Shape`, as it inherits from `Triangle` which inherits from `Shape`. Keep in mind that C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance, so that chain inheritance is the only way to accomplish a similar behavior

Comment: @RubensFarias you can also use interfaces to separate shared semantics from inheritance.

Comment: It sucks that C# does not allow multiple inheritance though. But thanks guys, I appreciate your feedback. Triangle class probably just needs a constructor with the values passed through from the base class, and then RightTriangle can inherit from Triangle. Thanks Again. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It depends".

If the types are immutable, where "modifying" operations return a new instance then this could work.

But if there are mutating operations then it will not.

Consider:

```
Rectangle rect = new Square(10); // Sides of length...
rect.SetWidth(20);
```

Does that mean `rect` is no longer a square, does it throw, or does it set the height as well? All three results are bad (and violate [Liskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

In the immutable case `rect.SetWidth` would return a new instance, each subtype would need to be written with logic to handle switching types when required (eg. in the above `rect.SetWidth(10)` could return a `Square` because the sides remain the same length).

While geometrically the hierarchy works, that is because in geometry all operations create new shapes and you then look at the properties of the new shape to classify it. In a statically typed language with mutable objects neither of those restrictions applies.

Answer (score 1):

Part I:
**Can it be possible for RightTriangle to inherit directly from Shape**
`Yes,` if RightTriangle does not inherit from Traingle
`No,` If RightTriangle inherit from Traingle --> C# Does not support multi inheritance -> compile error

Part II:
**Given that it is also a shape**
Same here if RightTriangle inherit from Shape then you can cast it as a Shape.